# Confidence interval on sum of differences

Tags: regression, time-series, confidence-interval, residuals

TLDR: I am performing a regression on some time series data to 'forecast' it. I then want to compare the forecast to reality and get some confidence intervals on the cumulative difference of the forecast to the actual data.

I have some data $y_1, y_2, ..., y_n$. I have have a regression formula to try to predict the value of $y_i$ given other data on the same day. Call this $y'_i$. I can calculate the sum of differences up until some point $t$ by doing $C(t) := \sum_{i=1}^{t}(y_i-y'_i)$. This represents the cumulative difference between the model and the actual data.

I can calculate a confidence interval for each $y'_i$ but I would like to calculate a confidence interval for $C(t)$. Is there a known formula for this?

Below is an image which will hopefully explain further. The blue line on the top graph is the forecast, the black line is the observed data. The bottom graph is the cumulative difference between the the two lines from some given point. This is the value which I would like to put a confidence interval on.

[image: Cumulative difference graph]